Spark map() operation fails with NotSerializableException
I am encountering a NotSerializableException while using a map() transformation in Spark, despite the object used in the transformation being serializable. The issue arises when I try to apply a function to an RDD using a lambda, which references a org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansModel object.
I have a scoringFunction, defined as follows:
public SerializableFunction<Row, Row> scoringFunction(final Schema schema) {
    final SerializableFunction<Row, org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector> rowToVector = rowToMlVector(dataset);

    final SerializableFunction<org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector, Integer> predict = v -> {
        return model.predict(v);  // 'model' is the machine learning model
    };

    final SerializableFunction<Integer, Row> toRow = someOtherFunction();
    return new ChainedMapFunction<>(rowToVector, predict, toRow);
}

When I try to apply the scoringFunction on my dataset like this:
final Mappable<Row> scoredRDD = rdd.map(row -> scoringFunction.apply(row));
It fails with org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable exception.
I did check if the KMeansModel is serializable using a simplified lambda expression and it passed without any error:
javaSparkContext.parallelize(Collections.singletonList(1))
    .map(x -> {
        System.out.println(model);
        return x;
    })
    .collect();

The same scoring function worked with org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel object and same implementation. I suspect the issue may be related to the following line in my scoringFunction:
final SerializableFunction<org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector, Integer> predict = v -> {
    return model.predict(v);  // 'model' is the machine learning model
};

However, I don’t fully understand why this specific code causes a serialization issue in this case.

Why does this lambda function fail with the "Task not serializable" exception in this context?
What exactly am I missing with regards to Spark’s serialization mechanism?
How can I resolve this issue? Should I explicitly serialize the model or handle the model differently in the function?

